# Google script trouble escaping characters in a string containing an email address

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, escaping

I have a script that takes a string and attempts to construct an email address from it.

```
var email = "";
var consultantName = "John Smith";

var array = consultantName.split(' ');
var firstName = array[0].toString();
var lastName = array[1].toString();

email += firstName + '.' + lastName + '@company.com.au';
```

However, when debug the email variable reads as "John.Smith@company.(class)" ??

I tried putting a single \ in front of ".au" and that didn't help so I put two \ in front and it ended up reading as "John.Smith@company.com\.au"

No matter what i try I can't get it to escape the characters properly to construct the email address.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be working for me... how are you debugging?

Comment: Besides adding the details of how you are debugging add a [mcve].

Comment: I was just using the built in debugger in the Google Script editor. I just put break points on each of the lines above to see what was getting written to each variable. The screen shot here shows what I am talking about in terms of the value of the "email" variable. - https://ibb.co/ftrHKJ

Comment: Just to provide further background.. this is part of a larger script that takes a name from a field submitted on a Google Form and send an email to it. I have tested it manually by setting the 'email' var to just my email and it worked.. So just need to work out why this string isn't being escaped properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that my script actually worked once i setup the permissions correctly. It seems that Google Script's debugger just likes displaying results for a string that way once you introduce two or more full stops.. Very strange.